# Undefined in Node.js API request function's return

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, undefined

I've been trying many solutions, but nothing helped... I have function, which does the GET API request and returns JSON parsed response. Console.log works and returns parsed response, but when I replace it with return, it stops to work and logs 'Response is undefined'. I also tried to declare 'dt' outside the function.

```
function apiRequest(apiPath) {
const https = require(nodeprotocol);
var req = https.request(apiPath, res => {
    res.on('data', dt => {
    return JSON.parse(dt); // edited from: return dt;
    });
});

req.on('error', error => {
  console.error(error);
});
req.end();
}

console.log('Response is ' + apiRequest('api data here'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not sending the right request back. Instead of return dt you might want to send response as json. That might look like this:

```
var req = https.request(apiPath, res => {
    res.on('data', dt => {
        res.json(dt);
    });
});
```

Comment: You're right, but it says to me json() is not a function. I edited it to 'return JSON.parse(dt)', this worked to me when I used console.log, not return, but I want the JSON parsed response to be returned by the function apiRequest so I can work with it

Comment: the `res` returned in your callback code is not the express'es `res`, var names just need to be changed

Comment: Like this?  @LawrenceCherone

`function apiRequest(apiPath) {
const https = require(nodeprotocol);
var req = https.request(apiPath, inside => {
    inside.on('data', dt => {
    return JSON.parse(dt);
    });
});

req.on('error', error => {
  console.error(error);
});
req.end();
}

console.log('Height is ' + apiRequest('/abc/def'));`

Comment: It still results as 'Height is undefined'. I think my problem is that variable dt is undefined outside the function, but I don't know how to do it